# Update cmis:name of object (document) with Apache Chemistry Php Library

Tags: php, cmis, apache-chemistry

I've one objectId and I want to change his name (for example) with Apache Chemistry PHP Library.

I try to use updateProperties method that Chemistry library provide... but I can't see the change. ¿What happen?

```
$test  = new CMISService($repo_url, $repo_username, $repo_password);
$id = 'ddb6eabd-a862-4e6b-9251-32b6e73300d7';  //existing objectId of the document that his name now is PRUEBAS.

$obj = $test->updateProperties($id, array('cmis:name' => 'PRUEBAS_MODIFIED'));

var_dump($cmis_repo->getObject($obj->id)); // I see that cmis:name continue PRUEBAS instead of PRUEBAS_MODIFIED ¿why?
```

Can I change the name of a document?

However I can change the cmis:description property perfectly... Why cmis:name I can't?

Answer (score 1):

I compared the request sent by cmislib (python) and a Apache Chemistry PHP client fork on github and found that the latter sends the following atom request:

```
  <atom:title>PRUEBAS</atom:title>
  <atom:summary>PRUEBAS</atom:summary>
  <cmisra:object>
    <cmis:properties>
      <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name">
        <cmis:value>PRUEBAS_MODIFIED</cmis:value>
     </cmis:propertyString>
    </cmis:properties>
  </cmisra:object>
```

The python client sends the new name in the `<atom:title>` tag. I tried to remove the `<atom:title>` and `<atom:summary>` tags and send the text via `curl --upload-file` to Alfresco and this worked correctly.

So my guess is that Alfresco considers first the value of the `<atom:title>` tag (when try to update `cmis:name` property) and falls back to the value of the `<cmis:value>` tag.

IMHO, it can be considered a bug of the php client library which should not be very difficult to fix.

Comment: Thanks erny. 
I've try to work with this other library https://github.com/dkd/php-cmis-client that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

erny was on the right track.

```
public function renameObject($objectId, $name)
{
    $properties = array(
        'cmis:name' => $name
    );
    $options = array(
        'title' => $name,
        'summary' => $name,
    );
    return $this->repository->updateProperties($objectId, $properties, $options);
}
```

That worked for me, actually you only need the title in in the options array to change names